# Why are these methods not dynamically defined at runtime by define_method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

So I have the following class below in a Rails 4.2 app that uses *define_method* to dynamically define class methods at runtime.  When I boot up the rails console it says that the Dynamic.kite_flying and Dynamic.tail_flying methods don't exist.  Is there something I'm missing to define these methods when I invoke them on the Dynamic class?

```
class Dynamic
  def self.hello_world
    puts "hello"
  end
  ["kite", "tail"].each do |arg|
    define_method("self.#{arg}_flying") do |word_name, list|
      puts "hello some dynamic #{arg}_flying"
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: The Rails tag is not appropriate here. You encountered the problem in a Rails app, but it's really a pure-Ruby question. Some readers who filter out Rails questions may miss your question because of the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`define_method` doesn't define class methods, it defines instance methods. You want `define_singleton_method` to define class methods in the code you have above.

Comment: Note that the methods *do* get defined just fine. You defined two methods named `self.kite_flying` and `self.tail_flying`. Those are illegal names for methods, but Ruby won't stop you from defining them, and you can still call them using reflection: `foo = Dynamic.new; foo.send(:'self.kite_flying', nil, nil) # hello some dynamic kite_flying`. You can also see that they are defined: `Dynamic.public_instance_methods(false).grep(/flying/) # => [:'self.kite_flying', :'self.tail_flying']`.

Comment: It's not accurate to say "`define_method` doesn't define class methods". If you replace the line `define_method("self.#{arg}_flying") do |word_name, list|` with  `singleton_class.send(:define_method, "#{arg}_flying") do |word_name, list|`, then `Dynamic.methods(false)
 #=> [:hello_world, :kite_flying, :tail_flying]` and `Dynamic.kite_flying 1,2 #=>
hello some dynamic kite_flying`. (The arguments `1` snd `2` are arbitrary, but two are needed.

Comment: Well, even there it's defining an instance method, just that the instance you're providing is the `singleton_class` instance. But `define_method` itself is still defining an instance method on the receiver. Only `define_singleton_method` wraps up the functionality so that it's defining class methods on the receiver itself.